# Reference for Elliptic PDE on $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: reference-request, elliptic-pde

Could anyone suggest a textbook, article, or lecture notes that covers elliptic PDE theory (existence, uniqueness, regularity) on all of $\mathbb{R}^d$, as opposed to the Dirichlet or Neumann problem on some bounded subset?  I emphasize I am interested in a treatment that concerns the elliptic operators with variable coefficients that precludes a Fourier transform based solution.  I found that Krylov's textbook (Lectures on Elliptic and Parabolic Equations in Sobolev Spaces) treats the problem, but I was curious if there were any others.

Answer (score 4):

The following book might be helpful:

> *Elliptic Partial Differential Equations: Volume 1: Fredholm Theory of Elliptic Problems in Unbounded Domains* by Vitaly Volpert (Birkhäuser, 2011) 
>   http://books.google.com/books?isbn=3034605374